# Declaring a datasource connection in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datasource

I am having an issue with the syntax for declaring a connection to an SQL database. The code I am currently using to declare it is as so:

```
Dim  connection As SqlConnection = 'Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\KES\Kana List.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30'
```

However when I use this syntax, the equals sign is highlighted and Visual Studio returns an "expression expected" error.

I have also tried declaring the connection as a string like so:

```
Dim  connection As string = 'Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\KES\Kana List.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30'
```

This also produces the same error. How do I prevent this error and is this the correct way to declare the connection?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: apostrophes are not quotes in VB, they are comment markers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Dim connectionString AS String = "Server=my_server;Database=name_of_db;User Id=user_name;Password=my_password"
```

then `Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)` should work.